# NestJS Manually Run Cron Job from Endpoint

Tags: cron, nestjs

I am trying to manually start a cron job by hitting an endpoint on a controller that uses the SchedulerRegistry class to start the job. I am expecting Hello World! to be logged by the cron job but nothing happens.

From debugging I can see that the job is not undefined when pulling it in with the SchedulerRegistry  so I'm not sure why it's not running. Any ideas?

Minimal Reproduction Here: https://gitlab.com/hactaviusxi/test-cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`job.start()` restarts a job that has been stopped.

> The getCronJob() method returns the named cron job. The returned CronJob object has the following methods:
>
> stop() - stops a job that is scheduled to run.
>
> start() - restarts a job that has been stopped.
>
> setTime(time: CronTime) - stops a job, sets a new time for it, and then starts it
>
> lastDate() - returns a string representation of the last date a job executed
>
> nextDates(count: number) - returns an array (size count) of moment objects representing upcoming job execution dates.

That's [from the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#dynamic-schedule-module-api). Seems like you might want to use `setTime` instead of `start`, or create a `new CronJob()`and reference the method you want to run as the handler for the job.